# Regaining access to ddwrt

Tags: networking, dd-wrt

I have a secondary router which is running dd-wrt, and configured as a wireless repeater on my home network. It functions perfectly well, but I would like to log in to change the settings.

I am currently connected to the router via ethernet. This router is on IP 192.168.1.1, but the connection is refused when I try to access it in a browser.

So I ran a scan on the IP.

```
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh
23/tcp filtered telnet
53/tcp open     domain
```

I tried these commands to access the router:

```
ssh root@192.168.1.1 -p 22
ssh admin@192.168.1.1 -p 22
ssh my_username@192.168.1.1 -p 22
telnet 192.168.1.1 23
telnet 192.168.1.1
```

In each case, the connection times out with no response.

Is there anything else I can try to access the router? I could do a hard reset, but would prefer to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Can you access the router via GUI?

Comment: No, typing 192.168.1.1 into a browser gets rejected

Comment: 192.168.1.1 is an odd address for a wireless repeater bridge. It is more suitable for your main router. Are you sure the dd-wrt has this address?

Comment: I am _almost_ sure, as that's how I remember it, and I did scan it. But is there some way to verify it?  I know that my primary router is on 192.168.0.1

Comment: If your primary router is 192.168.0.1, how can your wireless repeater be on 192.168.1.1? A wireless repeater is supposed to be something that allows the whole LAN to be on the same subnet, 192.168.0.0/24, see here: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge

Comment: Thank you, that looks like the clue I'm after.  It looks like I am mistaken, and the secondary router is a wireless repeater, NOT a wireless repeater bridge. I am still stuck, but at least better understanding the problem!

Comment: [edited question accordingly]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Marius Matutiae's comment, I was able to solve my problem by setting up an IP address on the correct subnet (192.168.1.0/24). After doing that, the web gui is accessible as normal.